why does the image show as null in the table?
So I am trying to display an image in mysql table even though i have tried to change the image and the path It still does not show up even my friend tried it with different images and paths but still show as null
CREATE DATABASE restaurant;
USE restaurant;

CREATE TABLE item (
    item_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    item_price DECIMAL(9 , 2 ),
    item_type VARCHAR(50),
    item_calorie INT,
    item_image longBLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY (item_id)
);
INSERT INTO item (item_name, item_price, item_type, item_calorie, item_image)
VALUES ('steak', 3500.00, 'food', 500, LOAD_FILE('D:\\dice.jpg')),
       ('tea', 4000.00, 'drink', 200, LOAD_FILE('D:\\ronaldo2.jpg')),
       ('noodles', 2500.00, 'food', 450, LOAD_FILE('D:\\ronaldo2.jpg')),
       ('chicken', 5500.00, 'food', 600, LOAD_FILE('D:\\ronaldo2.jpg')),
       ('tart', 700.00, 'food', 150, LOAD_FILE('D:\\ronaldo2.jpg'));


"still does not work" if you want to work with computers, you need more insight than "does or does not work".    You'll be getting an error message when it doesn't work.  What does the error message say?

@oscar isn't this is how you load images you provide the path by string?

@oscar I don't think that's a problem. MySQL will automatically convert strings to blobs.

What do you see if you just do SELECT LOAD_FILE('D:\\dice.jpg');?

The simplest explanation is load_file did not load the file. This is probably because it didn't find it. It didn't find it because load_file runs on the server. It's looking for your file on the MySQL server. From the docs:

To use this function, the file must be located on the server host, you must specify the full path name to the file, and you must have the FILE privilege. The file must be readable by the server and its size less than max_allowed_packet bytes. If the secure_file_priv system variable is set to a nonempty directory name, the file to be loaded must be located in that directory.

As Barmar suggests, debug with a simple SELECT LOAD_FILE('D:\\dice.jpg').
Instead, use load data with the local option.
Note that storing files in a database is inefficient. They take up a lot of space and they consume a lot of previous database server resources. Instead, store a path to the file.
For example, a web application wanting to serve a file. If the file is in the database it has to query the file, retrieve the file from the database, store the file, and then serve its copy. If you just store the path it queries the file's path and serves the local file directly.

just to add you need to use forward slash  / int the path rather than a backward one \ and follow the same steps as this answer
